# Does DateTime string contain value- wrong format of ToShortDateString?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Background: I'm trying to implement a search function. Part of my search function is the ability to search for a date (in German format). You should be able to enter "2014" and then you get every date with 2014 as year, or enter the whole date in German format (21.03.2014).

Unfortunately my code doesn't work:

```
_unitOfWork.StammdatenRepository.Get()
           .Where(s => (s.MyDate.HasValue 
                       && s.MyDate.Value.ToShortDateString().Contains(keyword)));
```

If `'2014'`, `'2012'`, etc are my keyword then it works. If I enter a whole date in the German format I don't get any result. I think this is because of the "wrong" format `ToShortDateString` method returns.

**Update 1:**
I'm sorry for the late reply/update. Couldn't get to the code until today. The if/else constructs doesn't work because my original code is way more complex (it's a complex WHERE-condition for Entity Framework). The user can enter a keyword and I'm looking in different columns for this keyword. One coulmn is the "BeginnVos", my date column:

```
string keyword = inputModel.Keyword.ToLower();
stammdatenEntityModels =
    _unitOfWork.StammdatenRepository.Get()
                .Where(
                    s =>
                    s.Geloescht == false &&
                    ((s.Auftraggeber != null && s.Auftraggeber.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.SerienNummer.Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.StammdatenKunde != null && s.StammdatenKunde.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.BeginnVos.HasValue && s.BeginnVos.Value.ToShortDateString().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.VosDauer != null && s.VosDauer.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.Geraetewert.HasValue && s.Geraetewert.Value.ToString().Contains(keyword))
                    ))
                .OrderBy(orderBy)
                .Skip(inputModel.EntriesToDisplay*(inputModel.Page - 1))
                .Take(inputModel.EntriesToDisplay)
                .ToList();
```

I tried different approaches, even like

```
s.BeginnVos.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Contains(keyword))
```

but I still get no appropriate result (list is empty).

The users enters "22.02.2013" (German format) but inside my database it's of course stored in the sql date format: 2013-02-22 00:00:00.000. Is maybe any convertion of the user input required?

**My solution**, thanks to Habibi:

```
string keyword = inputModel.Keyword.ToLower();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParseExact(keyword, "d'.'M'.'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);

stammdatenEntityModels =
    _unitOfWork.StammdatenRepository.Get()
                .Where(
                    s =>
                    s.Geloescht == false &&
                    ((s.Auftraggeber != null && s.Auftraggeber.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.SerienNummer.Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.StammdatenKunde != null && s.StammdatenKunde.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.BeginnVos.HasValue && s.BeginnVos == dateTime) ||
                    (s.VosDauer != null && s.VosDauer.Bezeichnung.ToLower().Contains(keyword)) ||
                    (s.Geraetewert.HasValue && s.Geraetewert.Value.ToString().Contains(keyword))
                    ))
                .OrderBy(orderBy)
                .Skip(inputModel.EntriesToDisplay*(inputModel.Page - 1))
                .Take(inputModel.EntriesToDisplay)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: What do you want to be returned if you enter the complete date, records for just that date, or records only matching year ?

Comment: Are you sure that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is returning `de-DE`?

Comment: If the complete date is entered, only this date has to be returned. I just want to compare the Date String, if it contains the string. I think a format is wrong somehow ...

Comment: Did you debug your code? What is the value of your DateTime's `ToShortDateString`? And what is `keyword`? Can you show an example values that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that the logic of comparing dates using the string representation is wrong. Instead you should convert your keyword to `DateTime` type object and then compare the `DateTime` objects. Like:

```
string keyword = "2014";
DateTime parsedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(keyword, "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
    // only year provided
    //Compare only year part
    unitOfWork.StammdatenRepository.Get()
               .Where(s => (s.MyDate.HasValue
                      && s.MyDate.Value.Year == parsedDate.Year));
}
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(keyword, "d.M.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
    //Complete date provided
    //compare complete date
    unitOfWork.StammdatenRepository.Get()
                .Where(s => (s.MyDate.HasValue
                          && s.MyDate.Value.Date == parsedDate.Date));
}
else
{
    //invalid keyword
}
```

The other issue you could run into with your current logic is, if your LINQ query is executing against a data provider for example Entity framework, then you might end up with the exception that `ToShortDateString` is not supported. Because ORMs would translate the LINQ query to under lying data source language, *(May be SQL in case of SQL Server)*

You can use a number of formats. *(notice the single `d` and `M` in format `d.M.yyyy`, It will be good enough for single/double digits day/month part respectively, if that is not the requirement then you can use `dd.MM.yyyy` format)*

Comment: Thank you very much. You led me to my solution. Parsing my keyword to DateTime helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring):

> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is
>   **culture-sensitive**. It reflects the pattern defined by the **current
>   culture's DateTimeFormatInfo** object. For example, for the en-US
>   culture, the standard short date pattern is "M/d/yyyy"; for the de-DE
>   culture, it is "dd.MM.yyyy"; for the ja-JP culture, it is "yyyy/M/d".
>   The specific format string on a particular computer can also be
>   customized so that it differs from the standard short date format
>   string.

So if you want to use your keyword strictly in German format, you can use explicit format `s.MyDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Contains(keyword)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're setting the correct culture?

From [DateTime.ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object. For example, for the en-US culture, the standard short date pattern is "M/d/yyyy"; for the de-DE culture, it is "dd.MM.yyyy"; for the ja-JP culture, it is "yyyy/M/d". The specific format string on a particular computer can also be customized so that it differs from the standard short date format string.

If you're not setting the culture to `de-DE`, `ToShortDateString` will return dates formatted with the `en-US` locale (i.e. `09/30/2014` instead of `30.09.2014`).